# Need to create new file each time if file size is greater then certain size

Tags: linux

I need help to solve one issue on which currently I am working on. I am writing C code to create file and check file size. But I want to create new file each time if file size if greater than certain size. Currently I am planning to create maximum 7 files and then again start overwriting first created file. I am not sure what solution work here.

I need to write this code in C. Let me know if someone can chime in here, that will be very great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried so far (see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: If you are continually writing to each file without opening/closing you can simply use `ftell()`, see [man 3 fseek](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html). If you are opening/closing or moving around in the file, you can use `fseek()`, then `ftell()`. Your other option is to call `stat()` on the file  See [man 2 stat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) If you have problems, include your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: actually what I want is, Let's say I opened one file, writing data into it, I can check file size, using ftell and when its more then 50Mb then I need write into different file.